# How should I improve my English learning routine?

Tags: english

I'm trying to improve my English level.

Those are what I do every day:

- I read texts 2.5 hours a day,
- I listen to podcasts about 1.5 hours a day,
- I learn 20 new words and repeat the previous words and phrases I've learned. (I learn 20 new common words a day, in addition to the words I've learned through reading and listening. I want to expand my vocab and be able to use the words correctly.)

My goal is to achieve as high a level as possible in the shortest time.
How can I improve my learning routine, and what "English assignments" should I add to achieve it?

(I hope I get C1 level, but I don't know if it is possible in a short time)

Comment: I don't think we can answer this question.  Too much depends on what resources you have available.  What seems to be missing from your schedule is any interactive activties.  But if you are not living in a country where there are lots of native English speakers and you don't have the money to pay for teachers this might be inevitable.  So without knowing your personal situation we can't give advice.  I'm voting to close, but my advice is "interaction" even if that just means asking questions here

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your routine is focused on improving your vocabulary, reading and listening skills. Even if it is a good routine, in order to get a C1 level you should also improve your writing and speaking skills.

**Writing skills.** Try to write in English as much as possible. You can try to participate in forum discussions, write comments, a personal diary, or even reviews of your favorite movie or book. The important thing is that you do some practice as “practice makes perfect”. Then, you can read what you wrote and see if it makes sense to you and if you can spot some mistakes. Also, if you know someone with excellent English skills or some native speaker, you can try to text them.

**Speaking skills.** Even if it may sound as an obvious suggestion, practicing your English with native speakers is the best way through which you can improve. However, if you lack confidence (especially at the beginning), you can start by talking to yourself. For example, you can do so in front of a mirror ((and this can encourage you to experiment with a wide range of words and new topics) or you can record your voice and listen to it.

Answer (score 1):

Wow! You practice a lot! Maybe you can improve by applying what you've learned. Increase your hours of exposure to native English speakers. The podcasts are great, but they are one sided, you cannot respond. But in conversation with a native English speaker, you will be able to think more critically in English. I would suggest internet applications if you do not have immediate access to English social settings. Even audible social apps such as Twitter, Clubhouse, Discord, etc. (none of these apps are strictly for learning English, as much as they are simply social apps).

Comment: Welcome to Language Learning!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're already doing an amazing job!

4+ hours is a lot of English in one day. I never managed that much.

If we're talking practically here, you need to improve your speaking as much as you can. There's a big difference between memorizing phrases and vocabulary and using them in an actual conversation. If you can't afford a native English speaker, I'd recommend finding a Phillipino teacher. They're very fluent and the quarter of the price of someone from the U.S

All the best